# Jupyter Notebook/Lab Not Launching

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am getting white screen in Jupyter Lab and a Black screen in Jupyter Notebook.
It is same either I launch from comand line or navigator.

```
(base) C:\Users\Satish>jupyter lab
[I 17:21:33.289 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from 
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 17:21:33.289 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is 
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[W 17:21:33.289 LabApp] JupyterLab server extension not enabled, manually loading...
[I 17:21:33.289 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from 
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 17:21:33.289 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is 
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 17:21:33.289 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Satish
[I 17:21:33.289 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 17:21:33.289 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/? 
token=b270fb632dd40eecd4f2d4bf150476cc9eaa5b514a20ac04
[I 17:21:33.289 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 17:21:33.351 LabApp]

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
    file:///C:/Users/Satish/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-7396-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=b270fb632dd40eecd4f2d4bf150476cc9eaa5b514a20ac04
```

This started happening after I pip install jupytertheam
I removed it and reinstalled conda, still this issue persists.

Comment: First, try to clean the cache/cookies/offline-content in your browser. If that doesn't solve the problem, run `jupyter lab build`.

Comment: I am getting this error
ValueError: Please install nodejs 5+ and npm before continuing installation. nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the nodejs website.

Comment: in web consol i am getting--- Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8888/static/components/preact/index.js?v=00a2fac73c670ce39ac53d26640eb542' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: Please paste the detailed error message from your web console into your question to help others better analyze the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. I downgraded the notebook version for Windows 10 python 3.6 anaconda environment.

```
 pip uninstall notebook 
 pip install notebook==5.7.5
```

If you are still having a problem. Then the following links may help:-
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4467

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1627

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean a white or black screen?
In your console it seems that jupyter is launched well.
Did you access the url mentioned in your console?

The following solution is based on my personnal experience. I hope this could help(even though i am not sure what your prob is):

copy http://localhost:8888 instead of the whole url with the token, normally there will be a login web page.
if not
try to use this cmd to redirect your port, it's possible that 8888 is being occupied:
jupyter lab --port=8889
and try http://localhost:8889 in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem
When I tryed start Jupiter Lab from prompt I received this error

Jupyterlab: Error executing Jupyter command 'lab': [WinError 5] Access is denied

searching a little,  I found that I have to start anaconda as admin

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. In desperation after trying a bunch of solutions, I installed Jupyter notebook from Anaconda applications list. As Jupyter notebook was installed, Jupyter lab also appeared as installed.

Answer (score -1):

To download in terminal type:

```
pip install jupyter lab
```

To open type:

```
jupyter-lab
```

--Do this over again if you have done it already--